# List of 70-573 exam resources

Tags: exams

What resources have you used for home learning to pass the 70-573 exam. There does not seem to be a book released yet to cover the exam.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Personally, I did the 3 week Certified Master training in Redmond. After that the 70-573 exam wasn't too difficult. Failing that, I recommend [Becky Bertram's study guide](https://web.archive.org/web/20151001055741/http://blog.beckybertram.com:80/Lists/Exam%2070573%20Study%20Guide/AllItems.aspx) (contains links to the relevant sections in MSDN, the Ignite training videos (if you can find them - I think [Paul Andrew's blog](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/pandrew/getting-started-with-sharepoint-2010-development) links to them), and some good books such as Sahil Malik's Building Solutions for SharePoint 2010.

Make sure to get some hands-on, for example work through [the labs](https://web.archive.org/web/20110412221859/http://www.microsoft.com:80/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=C010FC68-B47F-4DB6-B8A8-AD4BA33A35C5).

Good luck.

Comment: Thanks for the links. I am studying for thr 70-667 & 70-668 exams in unison at the moment. It would be good to get clearance from my boss to do the 3 week training. Can always ask...

Answer (score 16):

Critical Path has created a series of videos on YouTube which contain exam prep for both 70-573 and 70-576

[Critical Path on YouTube](http://www.youtube.com/view_play_list?p=B567137EA30A37BE)

Comment: Very interesting to watch.

Answer (score 8):

[Inside SharePoint 2010](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0735627460)

Comment: Is this a one stop shop for the exam?

Comment: This wasn't out when I did it, so I haven't looked at it yet, but I would expect it to be excellent. Use it along with the other resources.

Comment: I'm currently attending Critical Path Training "The Great SharePoint Adventure", which is being taught by Scot Hillier (one of the authors of the book). He said that the book goes right in line with what this course teaches.

Comment: If you read this book thoroughly, and work through the examples with a VM you will most likely pass the 70-573.

Comment: I have attended the official Microsoft classroom training for the 70-573 exam (Course 10175A) and I have the associated course book.  I also have the "Inside SharePoint 2010" book (I'm about 2/3rd of the way through so far), but I can confirm that the "Inside SharePoint 2010" book is excellent, and contains very similar content, touching on all the same subject areas, as the courseware book.

Answer (score 8):

In addition to Becky Bertram's blog post which has already been mentioned, I would suggest Wes Hackett's post. Both are linked below.

[Becky Bertram: Exam 70-573 Study Guide](http://blog.beckybertram.com/Lists/Exam%2070573%20Study%20Guide/AllItems.aspx)

[Wes Hackett: MCTS SharePoint 2010 Application Development 70-573 Study Guide](http://weshackett.com/2010/08/mcts-sharepoint-2010-application-development-70-573-study-guide/)

Answer (score 4):

Peter Munch gives some good links to articles in his blog

[Peter Munch: Links for 70-573 training](http://blog.petermunch.net/2011/02/12/links-til-70-573-undervisning/)

Answer (score 4):

I don't think there is a one stop shop for the exam, even when a exam study guide based book comes out.  All the book can do is cover the subject matter, if you aren't confident in one of the areas you need to explore it further with other resources (web, books, training etc)

The skills measured for 70-573 can be found here:

[Microsoft SharePoint 2010, Application Development: Skills Measured](http://www.microsoft.com/learning/en/us/exam.aspx?ID=70-573#tab2)

Answer (score 1):

[Sharepoint Ignite](http://www.sharepointignite.com) has some online traning materials.