# sharepoint developer Exam 70-573

Tags: development, exams

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [List of 70-573 exam resources](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/11612/list-of-70-573-exam-resources)

I'm trying to prepare for the sharepoint developer Exam 70-573.... I can't find any training books for this exam. Any help?

thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[SharePoint 2010 Developer's Certification: Certification Toolkit for Exams 70-573 and 70-576](http://www.amazon.co.uk/SharePoint-2010-Developers-Certification-Toolkit/dp/0470912340)

That book actually seems unavailable now... You could just get a generic SP2010 book, like this: [Microsoft SharePoint 2010 Developer Reference](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Microsoft-SharePoint-2010-Developer-Reference/dp/0735639035/ref=pd_cp_b_2), and compare against the [MS Learning site for that exam](http://www.microsoft.com/learning/en/us/exam.aspx?id=70-573#tab2).

Comment: so, it looks like the exam prep books just haven't been published yet... Thanks,

Answer (score 2):

Becky Bertram has a good blogpost regarding [the Exam 70-753 here..](http://blog.beckybertram.com/Lists/Exam%2070573%20Study%20Guide/AllItems.aspx) and Joel Jefferey has a ['practice test' for the same exam here..](http://joelblogs.co.uk/practice-exams/practice-tests/)